# Empty object prototype is undefined

Tags: javascript

(I'm new to JavaScript) If all objects inherit their properties from a prototype, and if the default object is Object, why does the following script return undefined in both cases (I was expecting 'Object')?

```
obj1 = {}; //empty object
obj2 = new Object();
console.log(obj1.prototype);
console.log(obj2.prototype);
```

Pardon me if it's a silly question!

Comment: Maybe the following answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941 As the answer indicates; prototype is a property of instances of Function and is used as the first item in the prototype chain of instances created with that function. var c = new Object(); the Object instances called c would use Object.prototype as it's first item in it's prototype chain. But since c is not an instance of Function it does not have a prototype member. If you do var q = new Function() then q would have a prototype member

Comment: @HMR Yes, that adds to the clarity. I'm still very far from understanding the complete picture, but every bit helps. ^.^

Comment: Objects inherit via their internal `[[Prototype]]`, which is a reference to the prototype of their constructor at the time they were instantiated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.prototype` is not a property of a live object and thus it doesn't exist so it reports `undefined`.  The `.prototype` property is on the constructor which in this case is `Object.prototype`. For a given object in a modern browser, you can get the active prototype with this:

```
var obj1 = {}; 
var p = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj1);
```

A non-standard and now deprecated way to get the prototype is:

```
var obj1 = {}; 
var p = obj1.__proto__;
```

Comment: Does not make complete sense because I'm still struggling with the intricacies of JavaScript. Will accept this as answer, though. Thanks! :)

Comment: There is also `obj.constructor.prototype` but it's not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript's prototypal inheritance, you have *constructors* and *instances*.
The constructors, such as `Object`, is where you find the `.prototype` chain.
But on the instances, the prototype chain is not really accessible.

Comment: @RobG Thanks, I removed the comment about the `__proto__` property.